# Program crashes on accessing SSBO in shader

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d

Whenever I try to access an SSBO, I get an error, saying `atio6axx.pdb not loaded`.

My graphics card (AMD) drivers are updated, but funnily enough while searching for a solution I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/yuzu/comments/g8dptz/atio6axxdll_opengl_crash/) thread, which was posted only a few hours ago, so could this be a driver issue? I searched my PC and found the `.dll` but not the `.pdb`, could this be the issue? I've got VS set to loading symbols from Microsoft Symbol Servers but not NuGet.org Symbol Servers.

Relevant code:

Shader (simplified to only show necessary code):

```
#version 430 core

layout(binding = 5, std430) buffer test
{
    float t[];
};

out vec4 colour;

void main()
{
    colour = vec4(test.t[0], test.t[1], test.t[2], 1);
}
```

Creating the SSBO:

```
float test[3] { 0, 10, 0 };

glGenBuffers(1, &ss_id);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ss_id);
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * 3, test, GL_STATIC_READ);
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 5, ss_id);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0);
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: "*layout(binding = 5, std430)*" That should be `8` to match with the value in `glBindBufferBase`. Also, your `GL_STATIC_READ` semantic is wrong. If you don't intend to upload to it again from the CPU, it should be `GL_STATIC_COPY`, indicating that the CPU won't be touching it.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks for your response. The numbers are mismatched because I was testing different indexes incase that was the issue, but the program still happened even if they were the same. And thank you for pointing that out, I couldn't find much about which one to use.

Comment: "I get an error, saying atio6axx.pdb not loaded." THat is not an erorr, that's an additional warning of your debugger, which is both expected and not really relevant (as AMD's windows drivers are closed source, so you won't get debug symbols for that). So what is the real error? The driver crashing with some segmentation fault?

Comment: @derhass It's throwing an exception, saying `Access violation reading location`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this issue, I found out why it was happening. I was referring to the data in the SSBO with `test.t[0]`, when instead it should have been just `t[0]`.